# I'm returning the node with the maximum element in class AVL in Python but failed

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here the following is part of my code:

class TreeNode:

```
def __init__(self, value, parent: Node = None, left: Node = None, right: Node = None) -> None:
    self.value = value
    self.parent = parent
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    self.height = 0
```

Class AVL:

```
def node_with_maximum_value(self, root: Node) -> Node: 
   if root is None root.right is None:   
       return root 
   new_max_node = node_with_maximum_value(root.right)
   if new_max_node.value > root.value:
       return new_max_node
   return root
```

But there comes the error: AssertionError: None is not an instance of <class 'AVL.TreeNode'>

I don't know where I'm getting wrong. Could someone help me figure it out?

Comment: How is this "using recursion"?  It's calling some other method (that you haven't shown), not itself.

Comment: I made it wrong so it's OK right now. Sorry for my mistake

Comment: How has the tree been initialized? What exactly is the error when failing?